# combining 2 Dict into one Dict with duplicates key values

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have the below

```
group1 = ['R1' , 'R2' , 'R1']
group2 = ['F1 is Car' , 'F2 is bus ' , 'F1 is bike']
```

I want to make something like

```
group3 = {('R1' : 'F1 is car' , 'R2' : 'F2 is bus' , 'R3' : 'F1 is car'}
```

then I wan to search for word F1 and it should give me something like

```
result = {'R1' , 'R3'}
```

how can I accomlish this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can zip the 2 lists together to make a dictionary:

```
group1 = ['R1' , 'R2' , 'R3']
group2 = ['F1 is Car' , 'F2 is bus ' , 'F1 is bike']
d = dict(zip(group1, group2))
```

You can then find by value using a comprehension:

```
[k for k, v in d.items() if 'F1' in v]
```